# Where is the included folder rule in the new version of AIDE

Tags: debian, aide

Previously I use AIDE on CentOS 7, and it was easy to include and exclude AIDE folder from scanning

There was already predefined rules that it can include or exclude folder like below:

```
# Exclude subfolder
!/usr/src/

# Include this folder with rule defined in CONTENT_EX
/usr/    CONTENT_EX
```

but, with the new version of AIDE starting `Debian 10`, I don't seems to understand how this folder is included or excluded. But I just found out that they have this bunch of predefined rules in here: `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d`. How does this new AIDE know which folder to include and what rule to use when it is scanning for file or folder changes?

Another question is: What is the best practice way to write the new excluded or included folder? Should we put new rule in `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d` ? Found the `hidden` doc here `https://aide.github.io/doc/` but it does not mention anything about this.

I said `hidden` because this documentation is not published in the frontpage of `aide.github.io` but you need to type the sub url like this to get into that `/doc/`

Comment: Last time I read, AIDE needs at least 1 include rule to work properly, so the rule will there in `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at `/etc/aide/aide.conf`, you will find this line at the bottom:

```
@@x_include /etc/aide/aide.conf.d ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$
```

That line will include all scanning rules from `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/*`

In AIDE there must be at least 1 include rule for the scan to work. So, inside `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/` folder this is one of the example of rules that actually include the scanning folders:

```
99_aide_root
```

The above file has the following content:

```
# this is the catch-all rule that includes everything that is not restricted by earlier rules
# this rule is deliberately unrestricted
/ Full
```

The meaing of `/` is to include the `root` directory in scanning and the second argument `Full` means to use the rule that define as `Full` from `/etc/aide/aide.conf`.

So, basically `aide` has included everything in scanning using the rule above. So you don't have to care about the `include` rule. What you should care is the exclude rule to ignore some folders or files. So, to exclude some folders or files you can create a file in `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/myrule`

Inside myrule, you can put this:

```
# Exclude subfolder
!/usr/src/
```

and finally that folder will not be included in scan

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know if this work.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, about excluding subfolder. eg: `/etc/aide/aide.conf.d/31_aide_exim4` it has an exclude rule `!/var/spool/exim4/\\.rnd$`. How do I overwrite this rule from exclude to include (without changing the content of this rule).

Comment: @KalibZen I think you can just add that rule in `myrule` file that I showed to you. I haven't tested this but you can try. Add this `/var/spool/exim4/\\.rnd$` in `myrule` without `!` sign.

Comment: I thought it is working but actually I could not add that, I will get syntax error.

Comment: @KalibZen what is the error message ?

Comment: This is the error: `ERROR: /etc/aide/aide.conf.d/myrule:1: syntax error: unexpected token or end of file, expected newline`

Comment: The error is very clear, you need to have a newline after putting the rule (there must be at least 1 line). Try adding new line in that file like this `echo ""  >> /etc/aide/aide.conf.d/myrule`

Comment: thx bro, it's working fine now.